# MassTransit.Kafka batching

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit.Kafka for produce and consume messages in batches. When I try to consume message one by one everything works fine, but when I try to consume messages in batches I get an error:

```
Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Local: Value deserialization error
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Exception creating proxy (GreenPipes.DynamicInternal.MassTransit.Batch<Aiforfit.WSW.DataStructures.Events.UserEvent>) for MassTransit.Batch<Aiforfit.WSW.DataStructures.Events.UserEvent>
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_Item' in type 'GreenPipes.DynamicInternal.MassTransit.Batch<Aiforfit.WSW.DataStructures.Events.UserEvent>' from assembly 'MassTransitGreenPipes.DynamicInternal3c37dde6a7c744b796f7ac1cf544383b, Version=0.0.0.0, Cul
ture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

Looks like it's NewtonSoft deserealization error, but everything done according to MassTransit documentation. I've tried to convert UserEvent to Interface because every model in documentation is interface, but it didn't help.
Configuration:

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddKafka(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection section)
        {
            var config = section.Get<EventMessagingOptions>().Kafka;

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer();
                });

                x.AddRider(rider =>
                {
                    rider.AddConsumer<UserEventConsumer>(typeof(UserEventConsumerDefinition));

                    rider.UsingKafka((ctx, k) =>
                    {
                        k.SecurityProtocol = config.SecurityProtocol;
                        k.Host(config.Host, configurator =>
                        {
                            configurator.UseSasl(saslConfigurator =>
                            {
                                saslConfigurator.Username = config.Username;
                                saslConfigurator.Password = config.Password;
                                saslConfigurator.Mechanism = config.SaslMechanism;
                            });
                        });
                        
                        k.TopicEndpoint<Batch<UserEvent>>(config.Topics.UserEvent, config.Topics.UserEventGroupId, e =>
                        {
                            e.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            e.ConfigureConsumer<UserEventConsumer>(ctx);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

            return services;
        }
```

```
public class UserEventConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<UserEventConsumer>
{
    public UserEventConsumerDefinition() 
        => Endpoint(x => x.PrefetchCount = 500);

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(
        IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<UserEventConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        consumerConfigurator.Options<BatchOptions>(options => options
            .SetMessageLimit(500)
            .SetConcurrencyLimit(25));
    }
}
```

```
    public class UserEventConsumer : IConsumer<Batch<UserEvent>>
    {
        private readonly ICluster _cluster;

        public UserEventConsumer(ICluster cluster) 
            => _cluster = cluster;

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Batch<UserEvent>> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Message.Length);
        }
    }
```

```
public class UserEvent
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid(); 
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Looks like it's NewtonSoft deserealization error, but everything done according to MassTransit documentation. I've tried to convert UserEvent to Interface because every model in documentation is interface, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a topic endpoint, you still specify `TopicEndpoint<UserEvent>` for the TopicEndpoint, and consume `Batch<UserEvent>` in your consumer. When configured on the topic endpoint, using `ConfigureConsumer<UserEventConsumer>(ctx)` it will properly handle the mapping of a batch of events to your consumer.

Assuming you are on the latest version of MassTransit, it should increase the ConcurrentMessageLimit on the topic endpoint to match the batch message capacity.